# search query result in django

Tags: django, search, filter

Here is my model

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    published_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    details = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    crawler = models.ForeignKey('Crawler')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

And the view for the news is

```
class DisplayNewsView(TemplateView):

template_name = "news_listing.html"
#paginate_by = 10


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(DisplayNewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


    categories_list = Category.objects.all().filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    context['news_list'] = []
    for categories in categories_list:
        print(categories)
        for crawler in categories.crawlers.get_queryset():  
            #print(categories)
            print(crawler)          
            crawler_list = News.objects.filter(
                    Q(category=categories), 
                    Q(crawler=crawler) | Q(crawler=crawler))
            #print(crawler_list)
        context['news_list'].append(crawler_list)
    return context
```

I have displayed the news in template.
I want to search the news according to time. I mean the news from "date" to "date" as per the published date in news model.

My model for category is

```
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    level_1_words = models.TextField()
    level_2_words = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    crawlers = models.ManyToManyField('Crawler',related_name='crawler_name')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

Can anyone plz help to to search the news according to publish date.
I want it to be done like from "date" to "date" submit.
When user click the submit button I want the news to be filtered..

It would be great help if someone tell me how to download the searched news in csv too. thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to make that field of the date a DateField instead of CharField

This is how to query date range in django

```
News.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime(2014, 5, 30), pub_date__gte=datetime(2014, 1, 30))
```

Another example would be

```
News.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime(2014, 5, 30), pub_date__gte=datetime(2014, 1, 30)).exclude(datetime.date.today())
```

for more information on django queries check out the docs @ [Making queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: Ok I got it but how can I get the date value when user enters the date in search form

Comment: The form field should be a date field then it will accept only formats that are convertible to django date field. Try something like datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")